# Getting List of objects of same class

Tags: object-oriented

I have a class 'Task' which represents any Task that is done by an individual employee. For this class I wrote properties like EmpID, Priority, etc. and methods like `AddNewTask(),` `ArchiveTask(),` `MoveTaskToUser(int userid),` etc.
Then I wrote a method

```
public List<Task> GetAllTasks()
```

This seemed incorrect to me with regard to OOP. I thought any single task object should represent one single task and it doesnt seem right to call `taskObj.GetAllTasks()` because object taskObj should carry out methods on the single Task that it represents.
So I changed the method to static:

```
public static List<Task> GetAllTasks()
```

Now I call `Task.GetAllTasks()`. Is this the proper way to follow object oriented approach. Was the earlier idea of calling the method from single object correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static approach is a good start. You could also just write up a class that manages all tasks. You could then go like:

```
TaskManager.addTask(/*whatever params are necessary*/);
TaskManager.getTask(/*whatever identifier you desire*/);
TaskManager.getTasksOfEmployer(/*employer-id*/);
TaskManager.getAllTasks();
TaskManager.updateTask();
etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure the static approach *is* a good start.  Depending on your language I might make the code more difficult to unit test.

Comment: Not to undermine anybody but given the question I doubt the author is Unit-Testing his source. The static approach is still better than injecting a list of all tasks into every single instance of Task, design-wise. A managing class would be the best sollution, regardless of implementing the methods static or not.

Comment: wow, I just noticed a big typo in my last comment.  I'm glad you still understood it, though.  I'd be tempted to suggest the OP use the Repository pattern for Task CRUD operations.  I'm holding back on answering myself because I think others may have a better grasp of this than me.

Comment: @JohnSmith : Thanks for your answer. I guess currently I'll stick with the static method to keep code simple. If there are more such actions wherein multiple task instances need to be managed then I guess I'll implement the TaskManager.

Comment: @ronik See stuartmclark answer, in my eyes, that's the way to go. For simplicities sake, just use the TaskList class without the interface. Something like this really is the best way. And also the easiest.

Comment: @JohnSmith : I think what you are calling as TaskManager, stuartmclark is calling TaskList. The difference I see is that you are suggesting making update/add calls in the TaskManager whereas stuartmclark suggests only managing object instances with no data layer calls/ no modification in object properties(which should be left to the class). This point from stuartmclark seems right and that is what I suppose you are pointing at? I am unable to upvote it yet :(

Comment: Well, adding a function to TaskList to update a specific Task doesn't mean that the TaskList implements the logic, it just means you use TaskList to invoke a function on a specific Task object. TaskList.updateTask(taskId, arguments); retrieves the desired Task and calls it's update function. Unless you implement the Interface and type the List inside TaskList to ITask. Again, I think stuartmclark approach is very good, give it a shot.

Comment: The reason I used an interface for each Task was so that you can have multiple task types, i.e. WakeUpTask, CleanDBTask, SendEmailTask. Then each Task would handle its own dependencies in terms of data access etc. The Task List does not need to know about any of these, just needs to be able to call ITask.Execute()

Comment: @stuartmclark : In my case I do not have multiple types of tasks. But a separate class which manages task objects is the concept that I was searching for which you and John Smith have mentioned. Thanks :) . Incidentally, does this approach have any specific name?

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar in the past and I used a TaskList type of object which contained the list of Task objects and manages the addition, removal and retrieval of each of the Tasks. Each Task implemented an ITask interface which had a Name property which was used to retrieve a task.

```
public interface ITask
{
    string Name { get;set; }
    void Execute();
}
```

Each task would implement this interface and as such the class that manages the Tasks does not need to know about any particular, it just knows it can call the Execute method and a Task will carry out its action.

```
public class TaskList
{
    private List<ITask> _taskList = new List<ITask>();
    public void Add(ITask task)
    {
        //Check for null / duplicate task
        _taskList.Add(task);
    }

    public void GetTask(string name)
    {
        foreach(var task in _taskList)
        {
            if(task.Name.Equals(name))
                return task;
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public void Remove(ITask task)
    {
        if(_taskList.Contains(task))
            _taskList.Remove(task);            
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.